# Relation Between 2 columns

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL there are 2 columns in table column A and column B and if in column A continuously comes one 10th time and in column B 11th time comes true(B can be 1 or 0 between these 10 times ) so I want that column id of B.

```
+----+---+---+
| id | A | B |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 0 |
|  2 | 0 | 1 |
|  3 | 1 | 0 |
|  4 | 1 | 0 |
|  5 | 1 | 0 |
|  6 | 1 | 1 |
|  7 | 1 | 0 |
|  8 | 1 | 1 |
|  9 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
```

I need this (column B id) (Where Column A continuously come 1 (10 times) and Column B (11th id after contenious 10 time 1 in column A )

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? AND what happens if col a has 20 continuous ones - do you want every b from 10 onwards until A reverts to 0?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a running total in a sub query to help you with this on versions prior to mysql 8.0

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,A int,B int);
insert into t values
(1,  1 ,0),
(2,  0 ,1),
(3,  1 ,0),
(4,  1 ,0),
(5,  1 ,0),
(6,  1 ,1),
(7,  1 ,0),
(8,  1 ,1),
(9,  1 ,1),
(10, 1 ,0),
(11, 1 ,1),
(12, 1 ,0),
(13, 1 ,1),
(14, 1 ,1),
(15, 1 ,1),
(16, 0 ,1);

select t1.id,t1.a,t1.b
from 
(
select t.*,
        if(t.a = 1, @rt:=@rt+1,@rt:=0) rt
from t
cross join (select @rt:=0) r
order by t.id
) t1 
where t1.rt >= 10;

+------+------+------+
| id   | a    | b    |
+------+------+------+
|   12 |    1 |    0 |
|   13 |    1 |    1 |
|   14 |    1 |    1 |
|   15 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: suppose there are14 15 16 17 18 and so on columns then it's showing all values but I want only 13th id

Comment: Indeed - what would you like it to do - it's true that 15 has 10 continuous a's prior to 15 so it qualifies based on your spec.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated one. Using window functions available in MySQL 8.0, I would proceed in 3 steps:

- first compute row numbers in the overall group and in groups of `A` values
- then do a cumulative sum of `A` values within groups of consecutive `A` values (using the difference between the 2 above groups), while using `LEAD()` to recover the `id` and `B` value of the next record
- finally, filter on the record whose cumulative `SUM` is 10 and whose next `B` value is 1; the `id` of the next record is what you are looking for

Query:

```
SELECT leadID id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        SUM(A) OVER(PARTITION BY rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY id) sm,
        LEAD(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) leadID,
        LEAD(B) OVER(ORDER BY id) leadB
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            A,
            B,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY id) rn2
        FROM mytable
    ) x
) x
WHERE sm = 10 AND leadB = 1
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qY68YH8cftYANULRMEP4wD/0)** with your sample data yields:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 13  |
```