# How to get the correlations between columns, discover what are the most correlated columns and plot them in a heat map?

Tags: correlation, statsmodels

I have to discover what are the most correlated columns from a table, then plot them into a heatmap. Im new to the forum, so excuses if I post something wrong... Thanks!

Here is the head of my data:

['mc.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkAPV.png)

Comment: Please, give us more details, tables, database, lanaguage, images, code....

Comment: Maybe it's helps you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212676/relation-between-2-columns